# Oracle SQL grouping

Tags: sql, oracle, grouping

I am getting records as below:

```
PERIOD LABEL1 LABEL2 LABEL3 LABEL4
-----------------------------------
 1       12
 1              14
 1                     11
 2              10
 2                            09
```

and so on..
I want it like below:

```
PERIOD LABEL1 LABEL2 LABEL3 LABEL4
-----------------------------------
 1       12     14     11
 2              10            09
```

Hope its clear.

Comment: Can you add your existing query to your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only have positive values, you can use a mix of `nvl` and `max`:

```
select period,
       max(nvl(label1, 0)) label1, 
       max(nvl(label2, 0)) label2, 
       max(nvl(label3, 0)) label3, 
       max(nvl(label4, 0)) label4
from my_table
group by period;
```